# how can i set only left column on the google-chart api line?

Tags: javascript, api, charts, google-visualization

I need start left bar with value -20, but this code like on both sides

```
 vAxis: {
          viewWindow: {
            max: 30
          }
        }
```

ps.

Comment: example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts

Answer (score 0):

use the `vAxes` option to style a single axis...

left = `0:`, right = `1:`, `2:`, etc...

```
vAxes: {
  0: {
    viewWindow: {
      max: -20
    }
  }
}
```